# How to determine whether a DisplayObject has been rendered

Tags: apache-flex

I'm puzzled about whether the `visible` property of `DisplayObject` is:

- an *indication from Flex* of whether the display object is visible.
- an *instruction to Flex* to display the display object.

I'm asking because I'm automating some Flex tests using Flex Pilot, and I need to know for certain when a display object becomes clickable.  In the application I'm testing, *clickable* seems to mean *rendered.*

Given the nature of the application and my tests, I don't think it's feasible to watch for the `updateCompleted` event.  I need a way to detect whether the display object is visible based on the values of its properties and its containers' properties at a given moment.

I understand that even if a display object's `visible` property is true, it will be visible only if all of its containers are also visible.  This means that I'll have to extend Flex Pilot by writing an ActionScript method to determine whether the display object and its containers all have `visible=true`.  But I'm concerned that even that method won't tell me for sure that the display object is really rendered, and therefore clickable.

My puzzle comes from reading two descriptions from Adobe.

The ["About creating advanced components"](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ascomponents_advanced_2.html) document suggests that the `visible` property is set by Flex after the display object is rendered.  In this description, it is Flex's job to set the value,
so that value is thus an *indication from Flex* of whether the display object is visible.

On the other hand,
Adobe's [description of the `visible` property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#visible) suggests that the property is writable.  And the code sample suggests that if the application changes the value, Flex will respond by displaying or hiding the display object.  In this description, the application sets the value as an *instruction to Flex* to display the object.  I'm guessing that in this case Flex re-renders the display object (if `visible` changes from `false` to `true`) or its container (if `visible` changes from `true` to `false`).

So two main questions:

**Is the `visible` property used in both of these ways, both as an indication from Flex about the display object's visibility and an instruction to Flex about whether to display the object?**

**If the application changes `visible` from false to true, when does the display object actually become visible?**  Is it visible by the time the setter returns?  Or does setting the property merely schedule the object to become visible during some later event?  If it's the latter, that means there may be a duration during which `visible` is true, but the display object has not yet been rendered.  If that's the case, I'm at a loss for how to determine, from the state of the display objects at a given instant, whether a display object has been rendered.

Answer (score 3):

There are some key constraints for a DisplayObject to be rendered. First of all, it has to be in the display list. visible has to be set to true, otherwise it would be ignored from the rendering. The last key aspect is the so called [elastic race track](http://www.craftymind.com/2008/04/18/updated-elastic-racetrack-for-flash-9-and-avm2/) which basically describes when event handling, code execution and rendering occur. So, implementing event handlers for FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE is not so wrong, because those are dispatched when ever a property changes, which change the rendered representation of the component on the screen.

**Is the visible property used in both of these ways, both as an indication from Flex about the display object's visibility and an instruction to Flex about whether to display the object?**
Yes, the visible property is initially set to true by the framework before FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE is dispatched, so the Flash player won't draw the component in a state (i don't mean the Flex view states), which is some where between construction and having the complete initialized view.

**If the application changes visible from false to true, when does the display object actually become visible?** After the next render cycle happend.

Comment: The UPDATED_COMPLETE Event will fire whenever a 'render' event is complete.  A render event is the act of running commitProperties(), measure(), and updateDisplayList(); although these methods will be executed if they are invalidated using invalidateProperties(), invalidateSize(), or invalidateDisplayList().  So, an updateComplete event could be executed after any one of those methods--or all three--are exexcuted.  But, there is no guarantee that a property change will call an invalidate method.  If it doesn't; then the updateComplete.

Comment: That's what i basically said in the last sentence.

Comment: I'm not sure where you said that.  My comment was in response to: "So, implementing event handlers for FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE is not so wrong, because those are dispatched when ever a property changes"  updateComplete is not necessarily dispatched whenever a property changes.

Comment: You omitted the last part of the sentence "which change rendered representation on the screen." So any property which leads to an invalidation of the component's state (i mean the instance's state, not any mx.states.State).

Comment: Sorry, i'm no native speaker. I'll do better next time.